# Click event not firing in main view in Backbonejs

Tags: events, button, backbone.js, click

I have really weird problem. I am trying to implement "root" view which also works as some namespace structure. Same principle introduced in codeschool.com course part II. In this root view, I want to catch event "click button", but that's the problem. When I click on button nothing happened.

```
window.App = new (Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $("#app"),
  Collections: {},
  Models: {},
  Views: {},
  Routers: {},
  events: {
    'click button' : function(e) {
      alert("Thank god!");
    }
  },
  render: function(){
    //for test purposes
    console.log($("#app").find("button"));
    console.log(this.$el.find('button'));
  },
  start: function(){
    this.render();
    new App.Routers.PostsRouter();
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
  }
}))();



$(document).ready(function() { App.start() });
```

The HTML look like this

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div id="posts"></div>

        <button>Click me</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

And what's really weird is output from console.log in render function. Both selectors are same, even the context is same, so where is problem?

```
console.log($("#app").find("button")); //this returns correct button
console.log(this.$el.find('button')); //this returns 0 occurences (WTF?)
```

**EDIT**:
After little change at `el: "#app"`, still same problem. Problem was (thanks to @nemesv) in instantiating this class before DOM is loaded. But however, it's not possible to instantiating after DOM is loaded, because then it's not possible to use that namespace structure (eg. App.Model.Post = Backbone.Model.extend() ). But this "main view with namespace structure" is introduced in codeschool.com course as some sort of good practice. Solution can be found there [http://jsfiddle.net/BckAe](http://jsfiddle.net/BckAe/)

Answer (score 3):

You have specified your `el` as a jquery selector but because you are inside an object literal it evaluates immediately  so before the DOM has been loaded.

So the `el: $("#app"),` won't select anything.

You can solve this by using one of the backbone features that you can initilaize the `el` as a string containing a selector.

So change your `el` declaration to:

```
el: "#app"
```

Your click event is not triggered because you instantiate your view before the DOM is loaded so backbone cannot do the event delegation your you.

So you need separate your view declaration and creation into two steps. And only instantiate your view when the DOM is loaded:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: "#app",  
   //...
});

$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    window.App = new AppView();
    App.start() 
});
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45dhY).

Comment: I tried that before but nothing changed. Still same problem, click on button or any other event is not triggered.

Comment: The click event is not triggered because you instantiate your view before the DOM is loaded. Separate your view declaration and creation into two step. And only instantiate your view when the DOM is loaded. http://jsfiddle.net/45dhY/

Comment: Well, now this code works, but another problems occurred. Now I am not able to do something like App.Models.Post = Backbone.Model.extend(..) because it's undefined, AppView.Model.Post work neither. I need to put that into instance of that class but this is available after DOM is loaded...

Comment: Although now you have a different problem so it is better to start a new question with your new problem... I see now why it is not working. I should tell you that your design is very strange: you want to store your model definitions inside your main view. I would create a new object for the app and attach the main view on it... http://jsfiddle.net/BckAe/